# TikZ picture of field theory

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

I am currently still learning to use TikZ to add diagrams to my paper about field theory, but it seems that I currently lack the ability to use this tool flexibly. The diagram I want to create is as follows:
[image]
However, based on my understanding of TikZ syntax, I've only managed to create this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (Q1) at (0,0) {F};
\node (Q2) at (2,2) {D};
\node (Q3) at (0,4) {K};
\node (Q4) at (-2,2) {E};

\draw (Q1)->(Q2);
\draw (Q1)->(Q4);
\draw (Q3)->(Q4);
\draw (Q2)->(Q3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd like to ask some beginner questions:

- How do I turn line segments into arrows?
- How can I set the angle of the arrows precisely?
- How can I place two TikZ images next to each other?

Comment: 1. `\draw[->] (Q1) -- (Q2);`. 2. Change the placement of the nodes or choose an anchor when connecting the nodes (e.g. `\draw[->] (Q1.80) -- (Q2.-100);`). 3. TikZ pictures are treated by TeX like text, just place them after each other but not place an empty line (i.e. a paragraph break) between them. You've tagged this [tag:tikz-cd] but don't use it. Are the commutative diagrams? The package offers a better interface to place nodes in a grid (a `\matrix`) and draw arrows between them.

Comment: If they're not commutative diagrams, you can still use a `matrix` to place the nodes without `tikz-cd`.

Comment: For commutative diagrams like this you can also use https://q.uiver.app/ -- you draw it using a nice graphical tool and then it generates the tikz code to paste into the paper.

Answer (score 10):

You can make both diagrams as a single `tikzcd` to ensure proper alignment. Setting `column sep` with `between origins` ensures the two diagrams will have the same spacing. You can use `&[<length>]` to increase (or decrease if negative) column spacing as in the code below where additional spacing is provided between the two diagrams.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd, amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Gal}{Gal}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep={1.5cm, between origins}]
& K &&[10mm]& \Gal(K/K)\arrow[dr]\arrow[dl]&\\
E\arrow[ur] && D\arrow[ul] & \Gal(K/E)\arrow[dr] && \Gal(K/D)\arrow[dl]\\
& F\arrow[ur]\arrow[ul] &&& \Gal(K/F)
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

This demonstrates three simple approaches using plain PGF/Ti*k*Z i.e. without `tikz-cd`.

The first makes minimal changes to your existing code. It simply corrects the syntax and adds arrows.

The second uses `matrix of math nodes` from Ti*k*Z's `matrix` library to create the second diagram. This is a little more complex, but still doesn't require the contributed `cd` library.

The third uses `tikzcd`.

[image: two diagrams with similar placement created using two different strategies: minimal changes to MWE versus matrix of math nodes]

### Minimal changes

For the first case, we simply add `->` to the picture's options so that all lines drawn become arrows. We then change `->` in the `\draw` commands to `--` and switch one pair of node names to get the arrows going in the desired directions.

```
  \draw (Q1)--(Q2);
  \draw (Q1)--(Q4);
  \draw (Q4)--(Q3);
  \draw (Q2)--(Q3);
```

We also put the contents of the nodes into maths mode and add `baseline=Q2.center` to centre the diagram on the current baseline. By adding a similar option to the second `tikzpicture`, the two images are aligned horizontally at their centres.

### `matrix of math nodes`

The code for the second diagram is

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(gal-2-1.center)]
  \matrix (gal) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=15mm]
  {
    & \gal{K/K} & \\
    \gal(K/E) & & \gal(K/D) \\
    & \gal(K/F) & \\
  };
  \begin{scope}[->]
    \draw (gal-1-2.220) -- (gal-2-1.north);
    \draw (gal-1-2.320) -- (gal-2-3.north);
    \draw (gal-2-1.south) -- (gal-3-2.140);
    \draw (gal-2-3.south) -- (gal-3-2.40);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This time, we use `\begin{scope}[->] ... \end{scope}` to add the arrows. This makes no difference in the current case, but is useful if you want arrows added to a block of lines, while other lines in the same diagram shouldn't get arrows. We could also write

```
\draw [->] (<coordinate/node>) -- (<coordinate/node 2>);
```

to add an arrow to a single line.

```
  \matrix (gal) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=15mm]
  {
    & \gal{K/K} & \\
    \gal(K/E) & & \gal(K/D) \\
    & \gal(K/F) & \\
  };
```

`matrix of math nodes` sets up a `matrix of nodes` for nodes with maths content. `row sep` adds separation between the rows, which we end using `\\` as we would for a `tabular` or `array` outside `tikzpicture`.

`\matrix (<name>) [<options>] { <content> };` creates a `matrix` named `<name>` with `<options>`. `<content>` consists of nodes arranged in rows separated by `\\` and columns separated by `&`. Again, the syntax is familiar from `tabular`/`array`.

By naming our `matrix`, we make it easy to refer to the individual nodes in each cell of our matrix. `(<name>-<row number>-<column number>)` refers to the appropriate node. For example `(gal-1-2)` refers to the node at the very top because it is in the first row (`1`) and the middle column (`2`). We can then use this syntax to refer to the nodes for the purpose of adding the arrows.

```
    \draw (gal-1-2.220) -- (gal-2-1.north);
    \draw (gal-1-2.320) -- (gal-2-3.north);
    \draw (gal-2-1.south) -- (gal-3-2.140);
    \draw (gal-2-3.south) -- (gal-3-2.40);
```

The part after the dot specifies a particular anchor. For example, `(gal-2-3.south)` refers to the `south` anchor of the node in the second row and third column of matrix `gal`.

### `tikzcd`

```
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=15mm]
  & \gal(K/K) \ar[dr] \ar[dl] & \\
  \gal(K/E) \ar[dr] & & \gal(K/D) \ar[dl] \\
  & \gal(K/F) & \\  
\end{tikzcd}
```

Here `\ar` draws an arrow to another node in the matrix. `dr` means down and right; `dl` down and left. Maths is default here, so we don't need to do anything. A `tikzcd` diagram is essentially a `matrix of math nodes` with suitable defaults for commutative diagrams and a convenient shorthand syntax.

However, I can't immediately figure out how to align the diagram correctly.

[image: three diagrams using different methods of construction/syntax]

### Complete code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\DeclareMathOperator{\gal}{\mathrm{Gal}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,baseline=(Q2.center)]
  \node (Q1) at (0,0) {$F$};
  \node (Q2) at (2,2) {$D$};
  \node (Q3) at (0,4) {$K$};
  \node (Q4) at (-2,2) {$E$};
  
  \draw (Q1)--(Q2);
  \draw (Q1)--(Q4);
  \draw (Q4)--(Q3);
  \draw (Q2)--(Q3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(gal-2-1.center)]
  \matrix (gal) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=15mm]
  {
    & \gal{K/K} & \\
    \gal(K/E) & & \gal(K/D) \\
    & \gal(K/F) & \\
  };
  \begin{scope}[->]
    \draw (gal-1-2.220) -- (gal-2-1.north);
    \draw (gal-1-2.320) -- (gal-2-3.north);
    \draw (gal-2-1.south) -- (gal-3-2.140);
    \draw (gal-2-3.south) -- (gal-3-2.40);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=15mm]
  & \gal(K/K) \ar[dr] \ar[dl] & \\
  \gal(K/E) \ar[dr] & & \gal(K/D) \ar[dl] \\
  & \gal(K/F) & \\  
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```